# Where can I find information about kubernetes ID spec i.e. pod suffix ID length or replicaSet suffix ID length?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to find the above information but I cannot seem to find anything concrete.

I've tried looking at [k8s source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes) but it's a bit hard to find relevant bits there and I'm not sure I can rely on such information going forward.

Reason for this is I'd like to extract certain bit of data about pods without calling the API.

So having:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
grafana-79dcc6469f-zzgmh                               2/2     Running   2          4d

$ kubectl get rs
NAME                                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
collection-grafana-79dcc6469f                    1         1         1       4d1h

$ kubectl get deployment
NAME                                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
collection-grafana                    1/1     1            1           4d1h
```

I'd like to exctract `zzgmh` as pod ID and `79dcc6469f` as replica set ID.

Comment: But why? Can you share the use-case? Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: @ashu it's for data enrichment during logs and metrics collection,hence the goal to minimize api calls

Comment: Have you looked at Fluentd and FluentBit's Kubernetes plugins? Might accomplish what you're looking for, for logs. For metrics, you can do relabeling in Prometheus if you are using it. Either way, I think you can simply use regexes to extract these identifiers. As far as reliability is concerned, this will seldomly change in the future. It's a pretty stable base.

Comment: I'm doing something slightly different. I intend to add those fields in open telemetry collector's k8s processor.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with OpenTelemetry, but both Prometheus and ELK stack, use the full name of the pods and group pods that belong to the same replica set using their labels. And in my **personal opinion**, it is a much better approach than providing just identifiers which are more or less useless without proper context.

Comment: Looks like the name is generated by the API server and not the controller. Replica Set controller just passes a prefix to the API server. See [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/b9d2df810c89bde69cd790905ec937caf1c36d19/pkg/controller/replicaset/replica_set.go#L569) which lead me to [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/b9d2df810c89bde69cd790905ec937caf1c36d19/pkg/controller/controller_utils.go#L552) and then [this](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1#ObjectMeta.GenerateName).

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I find information about kubernetes ID spec i.e. pod suffix ID length?

The `simpleNameGenerator` function is used for name generation in many places.

```golang
$ cat kubernetes/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/storage/names/generate.go

var SimpleNameGenerator NameGenerator = simpleNameGenerator{}

const (
        // TODO: make this flexible for non-core resources with alternate naming rules.
        maxNameLength          = 63
        randomLength           = 5
        maxGeneratedNameLength = maxNameLength - randomLength
)

func (simpleNameGenerator) GenerateName(base string) string {
        if len(base) > maxGeneratedNameLength {
                base = base[:maxGeneratedNameLength]
        }
        return fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", base, utilrand.String(randomLength))
}
```

> replicaSet suffix ID length

[Since 1.8+](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/51538/files), the names have a 10 runes long [suffix](https://github.com/DataDog/dd-agent/pull/3563/files#diff-39e718425aecc2d45eb92af886071ad2R390) (consonants + numbers).
That is controlled via `func ControllerRevisionName` from `kubernetes/pkg/controller/history/controller_history.go` file.

```golang
$ cat pkg/controller/history/controller_history.go
// ControllerRevisionName returns the Name for a ControllerRevision in the form prefix-hash. If the length
// of prefix is greater than 223 bytes, it is truncated to allow for a name that is no larger than 253 bytes.
func ControllerRevisionName(prefix string, hash string) string {
        if len(prefix) > 223 {
                prefix = prefix[:223]
        }

        return fmt.Sprintf("%s-%s", prefix, rand.SafeEncodeString(strconv.FormatInt(int64(hash), 10)))
}
```

Additionally, if you are about introducing your own changes to `ReplicaSet` and `Pod` namings you might want looking at least into the `pkg/controller/deployment/sync.go` file that describes the usage of the `podTemplateSpecHash`.

Additionally you might want to check [Stern](https://github.com/wercker/stern) and [kube-fzf](https://github.com/thecasualcoder/kube-fzf) tools if all you need is to navigate through pods quickly or to tail logs.